# Facebook canvas app hosted on rails nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, https, nginx, facebook-canvas

I am making a Facebook canvas app using rails 3.0.9 and ruby 1.9.2. and using nginx as webserver. I am using paper clip to save images on my server file system.

The requirement is I want to post these images to user's wall as feed on facebook, the problem is facebook is not showing image preview there just the url of the image is shown there. As its in development mode I haven't bought ssl certificates and commented protect_from_forgery method in application controller.

Can anyone help me out how i can post these images so that facebook can get these images from my server.

Regards